# Does INDEX-MATCH lookup system have limitations with ascending/descending lists?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup-tables

**Solved** it was as stated at the 1st comment link, `-1` for `[match_type]` must be used with an ascending order look up list, and viceversa for `1`, which requires a descending order list.

**TL;DR** summary: The `[match_type]` entry for the MATCH function seems to be a variable I must enter depending on whether my list of lookup numbers is ascending or descending, is this the case and hence a limitation or am I simply using it wrong?

I am trying to evaluate readings from measurements. To do this evaluation I must rely on theoretical values calculated to compare the actual values to a perfect situation. To do this I have a defined table with all the calculated values. I then use the INDEX-MATCH system to lookup the closest theoretical value (for comparison) to my experimental one.

FYI the INDEX-MATCH is structured as follows:

```
=INDEX(Return_value_range, MATCH(Lookup_value, Lookup_value_range, [match_type]))
```

Below is an example of the beginning of my table:

```
    A           B            C
1  C           O           Zr
2  5.707       7.602       86.691
3  5.719       7.587       86.694
4  5.730       7.572       86.697
5  5.742       7.557       86.701
6  5.753       7.543       86.704
7  5.765       7.528       86.707
8  5.777       7.513       86.711
[ascending] [descending] [descending]
```

Here is an example of my values:

```
     D     E     F           G          H
1   Run  O      C      Zr (O index)  Zr (C index)
2   1    2.90   9.23   [formula]     [formula]
3   2    3.57   9.72   [formula]     [formula]
4   3    2.86   9.45   [formula]     [formula]
```

So my formula to lookup the Zr value in cell `G2` based off of the experimental O value in `E2`  would be as follows

```
=INDEX(B2:BXXX,MATCH(E2,C2:CXXX,-1))
```

This returns the values correctly however here is where it seems I run into an inherent limitation: for the formula in `E2` I **MUST** put the `[match_type]` value at the end of the `MATCH` function as -1 otherwise it returns me either a `#N/A` value.

Similarly this is also the case when entering the same formula to lookup the Zr value based off of the experimental C value in cell `H2`, except that the `[match_type]` value has to be +1 as follows:

```
=INDEX(A2:AXXX,MATCH(F2,C2:CXXX,1))
```

The `[match_type]` part of the `MATCH` function can have 3 value, as explained [here](http://thinketg.com/say-goodbye-to-vlookup-and-hello-to-index-match/), which are:

1. 0 for an *Exact Match*.
2. -1 for a *Nearest Greater Than Match*.
3. 1 for a *Nearest Less Than Match*.

My conclusion is that I have to choose the `[match_type]` based off whether the `lookup_value_range` list is either ascending or descending.

**Question**: Is my observation a limitation of the system or an incorrect use of mine of the technique?

Comment: @pnuts and so it is. I guess I overlooked that... So it is inherently the way the function works. Thanks for pointing out the obvious I didn't think to look into :).

Comment: I see so it would essentially be pointless to perform an approximate search with this function as it would return the first number it came across or the `#N/A` error.

Comment: Sorry I meant it would be useless if the list of the lookup array were random! That was the context I somehow managed to omit from my response! The Thursday slowness!